# Is there a GUI Keyboard Remapper App?

Tags: keyboard, mac, remapping

Running Ubuntu 15.02. Tried finding the keyboard layout tab and now I'm convinced it's gone missing with this latest release. Thus, I'm looking for a simple app that does the same thing... I'm a Mac user during the day and need my keyboard to function like my Mac's. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://www.wikihow.com/Change-Keyboard-Layout-in-Ubuntu) might help. If you are just looking for the layout, scroll down the page.

And are you correct with your terminology? Did you mistype? 15.02 means that you haven't updated your computer since February! If you haven't, please do so! :)

Comment: Hey Simon! Indeed you are absolutely correct, I meant 16.04... it was an über recent download so thank you for catching that. ;) As for the link you gave me, that did help a lot. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: I tried but it told me that I had to have 15 "rep points" myself before I could do that. So, I just hit the check mark... maybe that will help! :)